# Dynamically update feature style on menu selection event

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on a chloropleth map that compares two geoJSON values associated with Pennsylvania County features. The values are chosen though an html select menu, where `value="feature.properties.[data]`. The select menus (inside the legend control) initiate `function ratioFinder` via `onChange`, which evaluates the value of each geoJSON property, finds the ratio of the two, and uses the `function getColor` to give a chloropleth style to each feature.

I've gotten each county feature to update individually on `mouseout` using the `function onEachFeature` and `function resetHighlight`, but I'm hitting a wall on how to have all the features dynamically update each time a menu selection is made.

I'm thinking I just need another bit of code in `function ratioFinder`, since it is already initiated each time a menu selection is made, but I'm not sure what should be added (or if that's the right way to go about it).

```
//Variable contains the geoJSON data called by the preceeding script and adds it to the map.

var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = '<select id=select_a onchange="ratioFinder(this.value)"><option value="feature.properties.peopleCount">People</option><option value="feature.properties.farmCount">Farm Count</option>[.....]</select><br><br><select id=select_b onchange="ratioFinder(this.value)"><option value="feature.properties.peopleCount">People</option><option value="feature.properties.farmCount">Farm Count</option>[.....]</select>';
    div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return div;

};

legend.addTo(map);

//Adds styled geojson data to the map.

geojson = L.geoJson(PAcounties, {
    style: ratioFinder,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map); 

//Function is an if-else color-picker. Values are sent down to the 'style' function - this determines what color to display chloropleth shapes on the map.

function getColor(c) {
return  c === Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ? '#aaaaaa':
        //[.....]
        c >= 4 ? '#E7BD92' :
        c >= 2 ? '#E1CCB7':
        c >= 1 ? '#DCDCDC':
        c >= 0.5 ? '#B7CCE1':
        //[.....]
        c === 0 ? '#aaaaaa':
            '#aaaaaa';
}   

//Function calls attribute data from the select pull-down menus and finds the ratio between values for each county.

function ratioFinder(feature) {

    if (feature==""); 
        var a = eval(document.getElementById("select_a").value);
        var b = eval(document.getElementById("select_b").value);

    return {
        fillColor: getColor(a/b),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };  
}

//Function defines the hover-over styling of each county shape. Triggered by function 'onEachFeature'.

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

//Function defines the reset styling of county shape after hover-over event. Triggered by function 'onEachFeature'.

function resetHighlight(e) {

    info.update();

    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
}

//Function is an event listener that triggers when a county shape is moused over or moused out of. 

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
    });
}
```